# How native process can communicate to chrome extension (lastpass do this)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I know that lastpass extension have a binary component to communicate passwords between browsers (to firefox and IE). What mechanisms can be utilized by chrome extension to communicate with other system processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's a Native Messaging API coming soon.
[Source](https://plus.google.com/100132233764003563318/posts/jdTrmmZL9Xh)
[Chromium Commit](https://codereview.chromium.org/12300041/)
[Youtube Video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=H82-9hg1Plg)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to communicate with the system, then you have basically two options:

1. You can [embed an NPAPI plugin](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html), which, generally, is discouraged when not absolutely necessary (and even then :) ).
2. Your system process can run a web server with a well-defined API that your extension talks to. This ends up being message-passing writ large, but has the potential of being much more secure, since the processes can be independently sandboxed. WebSockets are pretty useful for this sort of thing, but a lot can be accomplished with simple HTTP requests to 127.0.0.1 via XHR.

Comment: I like the idea of a native app running a embedded web server on 127.0.0.1 that's a good idea.